# vtk build mac os x 10.10 , no rule to make target '...libpython2.7.dylib'

Tags: python, cmake, osx-yosemite, vtk

I am trying to build this [code](http://gitorious.org/vtkwikiexamplestarballs/vtkwikiexamplestarballs/raw/master:ReadDICOMSeries.tar) on Mac OS X 10.10 with vtk-6.1.1. After "cmake" I run "make" and it delivers me the following error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target ReadDICOMSeries
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ReadDICOMSeries.dir /ReadDICOMSeries.cxx.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib', needed by `ReadDICOMSeries.app/Contents/MacOS/ReadDICOMSeries'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ReadDICOMSeries.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

With homebrew I only have python 2.7.9 installed. Sorry, have looked around but could not find a solution to this problem and don't know enough about cmake to figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by

```
brew update
brew rm vtk
brew install vtk --with-qt
```