# No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib', needed by `lib/libcaffe.1.0.0-rc3.dylib'. Stop

Tags: python, macos, caffe

I am installing caffe on my mac 10.10 with cpu only model.

> [ 72%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/upgrade_proto.cpp.o
>   make[2]: ** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib', needed by 'lib/libcaffe.1.0.0-rc3.dylib'.**  Stop.
>   make[1]: ** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
>   make: ** [all] Error 2 **

First,I check the file `'/usr/lib/'` and found the `'libpython2.7.dylib'` exits but was useless then I copied a `libpython2.7.dylib` from   `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib`  that is my python's file

Finally,

```
make clean
make all
```

This error came out again. I checked the makefile in caffe/bulid/src/caffe/ but cannot found some url or libxxxxx. How can I fix this error?

Comment: You should try to use anaconda python instead. You can follow this link http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#compilation

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755739/vtk-build-mac-os-x-10-10-no-rule-to-make-target-libpython2-7-dylib